# Why is Weblogic work manager is rejecting work

Tags: java, spring, weblogic-10.x, workmanagers, commonj

I am using commonJ work managers running in web logic environment.

My setup is as follows:

My spring application context

> ```
> <bean id="workManagerTaskExecutor"
>    class="org.springframework.scheduling.commonj.WorkManagerTaskExecutor">
>     <property name="workManagerName" value="java:comp/env/wm/UVWorkManager" />
> </bean>
> ```

My web.xml file in WEB-INF

> ```
> <resource-ref>
>     <res-ref-name>wm/UVWorkManager</res-ref-name>
>     <res-type>commonj.work.WorkManager</res-type>
>     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
>     <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
> </resource-ref>
> ```

and my weblogic.xml file in WEB-INF

```
<work-manager>
    <name>wm/UVWorkManager</name>
    <min-threads-constraint>
        <name>min threads</name>
        <count>30</count>
    </min-threads-constraint>
    <max-threads-constraint>
        <name>max threads</name>
        <count>200</count>
    </max-threads-constraint>
    <capacity>
        <name>max capacity</name>
        <count>20</count>
    </capacity>
    <work-manager-shutdown-trigger>
        <max-stuck-thread-time>600</max-stuck-thread-time>
        <stuck-thread-count>100</stuck-thread-count>
    </work-manager-shutdown-trigger>
</work-manager>
```

After a while calling the service from SOAP-UI. I am getting the following error

```
commonj.work.WorkException: commonj.work.WorkRejectedException: [WorkManager:002912]OverloadManager max capacity rejected request as current length 20 exceeds max capacity of 20
```

I know as the maximum is set to it will be rejected but why doesn't it reclaim those threads? Even if I wait 15 minutes I cannot submit a new request. I have to reboot the service.

Answer (score 0):

The capacity includes all requests, queued or executing, from the constrained work set.
To verify the status of the threads, do a thread dump of the JVM.

You should set the JVM flag -Dweblogic.StuckThreadHandling=true to append WorkManager's name in log files when the theard dump is generated.

```
kill -3 JVM_PID
```